# section heading break new line

Tags: sectioning, horizontal-alignment, koma-script

i want to break my section heading in a new line.

```
\section{Underactuated mechanical systems \\ with servo constraints}
```

But the new line does not align with the first word Underactuated but align with the Section number 4.1. It looks not good.

```
\documentclass[
openright,
listof=totoc,
bibliography=totoc,
two‌​side,
fontsize=12pt,
e‌​nglish,
parskip=half,‌​
headinclude,
footincl‌​ude=false,
headseplin‌​e,DIV17,
BCOR16mm,
num‌​bers=noenddot,
2.1hea‌​dlines,
appendixprefi‌​x,
cleardoublepage=em‌​pty]
{scrbook}
```

Comment: the formatting of section headings depends entirely on the document class, and you have given no clues about which document class you are using.

Comment: Thanks David.                                                                                       I am not very familiar with Latex. The template is just from the institute given for my phd Thesis.                                                      The document class is like this: \documentclass[openright,listof=totoc,bibliography=totoc,twoside,fontsize=12pt,english,parskip=half,headinclude,footinclude=false,headsepline,DIV17,BCOR16mm,numbers=noenddot,2.1headlines,appendixprefix,cleardoublepage=empty]{scrbook}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chapter Section Subsection headings in one page alignment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/357192/chapter-section-subsection-headings-in-one-page-alignment)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A solution that does not require to go into the details of `scrbook` is

```
\section
  [Underactuated mechanical systems with servo constraints]%
  {\parbox[t]{15em}{Underactuated mechanical systems with servo constraints}}
```

The optional argument is needed for the table of contents and page headings.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrbook}
\begin{document}
\setcounter{chapter}{4}
\section
  [Underactuated mechanical systems with servo constraints]%
  {\parbox[t]{15em}{Underactuated mechanical systems with servo constraints}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @PeterYang Please unaccept my answer and accept the answer of esdd instead, it is definitely the better one.

Answer (score 9):

Use `\newline`:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\begin{document}
\section
  [Underactuated mechanical systems with servo constraints]
  {Underactuated mechanical systems \newline with servo constraints}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or you can redefine `\sectionlinesformat` to measure the width of the section number and use a `\parbox` for the section title text:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\newdimen\sectionnumberwidth
\newbox\sectionnumber
%\renewcommand\raggedsection{\raggedleft}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\sectionlinesformat[4]{%
  \sbox\sectionnumber{\hskip#2#3}%
  \setlength\sectionnumberwidth{\wd\sectionnumber}%
  \@hangfrom%
    {\usebox\sectionnumber}%
    {\parbox[t]{\dimexpr\textwidth-\sectionnumberwidth\relax}{\raggedsection #4}}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section
  [Underactuated mechanical systems with servo constraints]
  {Underactuated mechanical systems \\ with servo constraints}
\end{document}
```

---

BTW: Use `DIV=17` and `BCOR=16mm` instead of the obsolete options `DIV17` and `BCOR16mm`.

```
\documentclass[
%openright,% default
listof=totoc,
bibliography=totoc,
%twoside,% default
fontsize=12pt,
english,
parskip=half,
headinclude,
footinclude=false,
headsepline,
DIV=17,% <- changed
BCOR=16mm,% <- changed
numbers=noenddot,
headlines=2.1,% <- changed
appendixprefix,
%cleardoublepage=empty% default
]
{scrbook}
```