# Indent Section Heading for KOMA Class

Tags: sectioning, indentation, koma-script

Is there a way to make the indent of chapter and section so that the title of both starts math the same width? For the example: E of Einleitung and Z of Zielstellung directly aligned.

I am using this KOMA-class:

```
\documentclass[12pt, numbers=noenddot,parskip,headings=small,headsepline,listof=nochaptergap, listof=totoc,index=totoc]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[a4paper, includehead, left=3.5cm, right=1.7cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2.0cm]{geometry}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
beforeskip=-1sp,
afterskip=.25\baselineskip]{chapter}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
beforeskip=-\baselineskip,
afterskip=.5\baselineskip]{section}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
beforeskip=-.75\baselineskip,
afterskip=.5\baselineskip]{subsection}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
beforeskip=-.5\baselineskip,
afterskip=.25\baselineskip]{subsubsection}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
beforeskip=.5\baselineskip,
afterskip=-1em]{paragraph}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
beforeskip=-.5\baselineskip,
afterskip=-1em]{subparagraph}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Einleitung}
\section{Zielstellung}
\end{document}
```

[image: Indent for Section Heading]

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/373260/9057

Comment: Could you please add a [minimal but working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) starting with `\documentclass` followed by only the preamble code, that is needed to reproduce the problem, and followed by a document body from `\begin{document}` to `\end{document}`? This makes is easier and faster to help you. So please help us to help you.

Comment: Done, I added a chapter and section.

Comment: You should not copy the MWE of an answer to the question. Because that code does not show the problem but (parts of) the solution! If you have a question to an answer either add a comment to the answer or ask a follow-up question.

Comment: Please read the [documentation of `\chapterformat` and `\sectionformat` in the KOMA-Script manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf#desc:maincls.cmd.chapterformat) (or [same in German](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguide.pdf#desc:maincls.cmd.chapterformat)). You will find, that there are similar commands for all other section levels.

Comment: Also related: [Chapter Section Subsection headings in one page alignment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/357192/chapter-section-subsection-headings-in-one-page-alignment)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put the numbers in a box of the same width. Note that you cannot use `em` or `ex` here, because this would depend on the font sizes of the headings and therefore only be the same if the font sizes of all sectioning levels are the same, e.g.,

```
\newcommand*{\chapterformat}{%
  \IfChapterUsePrefixLine{\chapapp\nobreakspace\thechapter\autodot}{%
    \makebox[40pt][l]{\thechapter\autodot\hfil}%
  }%
}
\newcommand*{\sectionformat}{\makebox[40pt][l]{\thesection\autodot\hfil}}
```

This can be extended for all levels, but in this case 40pt are not enough:

```
\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{%
  \IfUsePrefixLine{\chapapp\nobreakspace\thechapter\autodot}{%
    \makebox[80pt][l]{\thechapter\autodot\hfil}%
  }%
}
\renewcommand*{\sectionformat}{\makebox[80pt][l]{\thesection\autodot\hfil}}
\renewcommand*{\subsectionformat}{\makebox[80pt][l]{\thesubsection\autodot\hfil}}
\renewcommand*{\subsubsectionformat}{\makebox[80pt][l]{\thesubsubsection\autodot\hfil}}
\renewcommand*{\paragraphformat}{\makebox[80pt][l]{\theparagraph\autodot\hfil}}
\renewcommand*{\subparagraphformat}{\makebox[80pt][l]{\thesubparagraph\autodot\hfil}}
```

But if (and only if) you want the same indent for all levels from chapter down to subparagraph you could also redefine `\chapterlinesformat`, `\sectionlinesformat` and `\sectioncatchphraseformat`:

```
\documentclass[12pt, numbers=noenddot,parskip,headings=small,headsepline,listof=nochaptergap, listof=totoc,index=totoc]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[a4paper, includehead, left=3.5cm, right=1.7cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2.0cm]{geometry}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
beforeskip=-1sp,
afterskip=.25\baselineskip]{chapter}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
beforeskip=-\baselineskip,
afterskip=.5\baselineskip]{section}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
beforeskip=-.75\baselineskip,
afterskip=.5\baselineskip]{subsection}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
beforeskip=-.5\baselineskip,
afterskip=.25\baselineskip]{subsubsection}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
beforeskip=.5\baselineskip,
afterskip=-1em]{paragraph}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
beforeskip=-.5\baselineskip,
afterskip=-1em]{subparagraph}

\newlength{\allsectionnumberwidth}
\setlength{\allsectionnumberwidth}{80pt}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\chapterlinesformat}[3]{%
  \IfArgIsEmpty{#2}{#3}{%
    \@hangfrom{\makebox[\allsectionnumberwidth][l]{#2}}{#3}%
  }%
}
\renewcommand{\sectionlinesformat}[4]{%
  \IfArgIsEmpty{#3}{\@hangfrom{\hskip #2}{#4}}{%
    \@hangfrom{\makebox[\allsectionnumberwidth][l]{\hskip #2#3}}{#4}%
  }%
}
\renewcommand{\sectioncatchphraseformat}[4]{%
  \IfArgIsEmpty{#3}{\hskip #2#3#4}{%
    \makebox[\allsectionnumberwidth][l]{\hskip #2#3}#4%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{\subparagraphnumdepth}% To show it for all levels

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter Heading}
\section{Section Heading}
\subsection{Subsection Heading}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection Heading}
\paragraph{Paragraph Heading}
\subparagraph{Subparagraph Heading}
\end{document}
```

You even could detect the needed number width automatically:

```
\documentclass[12pt, numbers=noenddot,parskip,headings=small,headsepline,listof=nochaptergap, listof=totoc,index=totoc]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[a4paper, includehead, left=3.5cm, right=1.7cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2.0cm]{geometry}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
beforeskip=-1sp,
afterskip=.25\baselineskip]{chapter}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
beforeskip=-\baselineskip,
afterskip=.5\baselineskip]{section}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
beforeskip=-.75\baselineskip,
afterskip=.5\baselineskip]{subsection}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
beforeskip=-.5\baselineskip,
afterskip=.25\baselineskip]{subsubsection}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
beforeskip=.5\baselineskip,
afterskip=-1em]{paragraph}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
beforeskip=-.5\baselineskip,
afterskip=-1em]{subparagraph}

\newlength{\allsectionnumberwidth}
\setlength{\allsectionnumberwidth}{40pt}% use at least 40pt
\newlength{\maxallsectionnumberwidth}
\setlength{\maxallsectionnumberwidth}{\allsectionnumberwidth}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\chapterlinesformat}[3]{%
  \IfArgIsEmpty{#2}{#3}{%
    \updateallsectionnumberwidth{#2}%
    \@hangfrom{\makebox[\allsectionnumberwidth][l]{#2}}{#3}%
  }%
}
\renewcommand{\sectionlinesformat}[4]{%
  \IfArgIsEmpty{#3}{\@hangfrom{\hskip #2}{#4}}{%
    \updateallsectionnumberwidth{\hskip #2#3}%
    \@hangfrom{\makebox[\allsectionnumberwidth][l]{\hskip #2#3}}{#4}%
  }%
}
\renewcommand{\sectioncatchphraseformat}[4]{%
  \IfArgIsEmpty{#3}{\hskip #2#3#4}{%
    \updateallsectionnumberwidth{\hskip #2#3}%
    \makebox[\allsectionnumberwidth][l]{\hskip #2#3}#4%
  }%
}
\newcommand*{\updateallsectionnumberwidth}[1]{%
  \begingroup
    \settowidth{\@tempdima}{#1}%
    \ifdim\@tempdima>\maxallsectionnumberwidth
      \global\maxallsectionnumberwidth\@tempdima
    \fi
  \endgroup  
}
\BeforeClosingMainAux{%
  \if@filesw
    \ifdim\maxallsectionnumberwidth>\allsectionnumberwidth
      \typeout{Rerun to get section number width right!}%
      \immediate\write\@auxout{\unexpanded{%
          \providecommand*\setallsectionnumberwidth[1]{}^^J%
        }%
        \string\setallsectionnumberwidth{\the\maxallsectionnumberwidth}%
      }%
    \fi
  \fi
}
\newcommand*{\setallsectionnumberwidth}[1]{%
  \setlength{\allsectionnumberwidth}{#1}%
  \global\allsectionnumberwidth\allsectionnumberwidth
}
\makeatother

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{\subparagraphnumdepth}% To show it for all levels

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter Heading}
\section{Section Heading}
\subsection{Subsection Heading}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection Heading}
\paragraph{Paragraph Heading}
\subparagraph{Subparagraph Heading}
% Compare after adding
%\setcounter{section}{99}\setcounter{subparagraph}{999}\subparagraph{More}
\end{document}
```

Note: You need at least two LaTeX runs to get the number widths correct, e.g., after activating the commented line before the `\end{document}`.

See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/357254/9057 if you want something like this on a per page basis instead of a per document basis.

Answer (score 3):

You could use something like

```
\newdimen\sectionnumberwdmax
\setlength\sectionnumberwdmax{1.25cm}% <- space needed for the section numbers

\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{%
  \mbox{\chapappifchapterprefix{\nobreakspace}%
    \IfUsePrefixLine
      {\thechapter\autodot}
      {\makebox[\sectionnumberwdmax][l]{\thechapter\autodot\hfil}}%
  }%
}
\renewcommand*\sectionformat{\makebox[\sectionnumberwdmax][l]{\thesection\autodot\hfil}}
```

Example:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt, numbers=noenddot,parskip,headings=small,headsepline,listof=nochaptergap, listof=totoc,index=totoc]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[a4paper, includehead, left=3.5cm, right=1.7cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2.0cm]{geometry}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=-1sp,
  afterskip=.25\baselineskip
]{chapter}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=-\baselineskip,
  afterskip=.5\baselineskip
]{section}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=-.75\baselineskip,
  afterskip=.5\baselineskip
]{subsection}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=-.5\baselineskip,
  afterskip=.25\baselineskip
]{subsubsection}
\RedeclareSectionCommands[
  beforeskip=.5\baselineskip,
  afterskip=-1em
]{paragraph,subparagraph}

\newdimen\sectionnumberwdmax
\setlength\sectionnumberwdmax{1.25cm}% <- space needed for the section numbers

\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{%
  \mbox{\chapappifchapterprefix{\nobreakspace}%
    \IfUsePrefixLine
      {\thechapter\autodot}
      {\makebox[\sectionnumberwdmax][l]{\thechapter\autodot\hfil}}%
  }%
}
\renewcommand*\sectionformat{\makebox[\sectionnumberwdmax][l]{\thesection\autodot\hfil}}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Einleitung}
\section{Zielstellung}
\setcounter{section}{9}
\section{Abschnitt mit zweistelliger Nummer}
\end{document}
```

Comment: For some reason this interferes with my  header and places the heading too close to the headsepline if I use `\usepackage[automark
]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\automark{chapter}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ihead{\headmark}
\ohead{\pagemark}
\renewcommand*{\chapterpagestyle}{headings}
\renewcommand*{\chapterheadstartvskip}{\vspace*{-\topskip}}`

Comment: Remove `\renewcommand*{\chapterheadstartvskip}{\vspace*{-\topskip}}` from your code.  It shifts the chapter heading upwards over the border of the text area.  The skip before the chapter heading is set by `\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=-1sp,...]{chapter}`. For more information see the documentation.